# Difference between redux nested selector and non-nested selector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have seen many example codes of redux and found that we use useSelector in mostly 2 ways.

1. nested

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
    
    export const UserComponent = () => {
      const name = useSelector((state) => state.user.name)
      const age = useSelector((state) => state.user.age)
      return <div>{name}, {age}</div>
    }
```

2. non-nested

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
    
    export const UserComponent = () => {
      const user = useSelector((state) => state.user)
      return <div>{user.name}, {user.age}</div>
    }
```

As you can see, with approach 2, I will end up saving lots of code repetition and I only need to create 1 selector.
So I wanted to know the difference, any performance benefits, etc.

Comment: It depends on what field you need, if you need many fields from `user` you wouldn't want to create a separate `useSelector` for each, however if you only need 1 or 2 fields like `name` and `age` you may be better off doing it with 2 `useSelector`'s so you can then reference it directly in your component.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between these two approaches, let's dive deeper into the `useSelector` hook and see how it works. So let's say you're the creator of this hook and you define it as:

```js
// this is your redux state
const state = { user: { name: 'Haseeb', age: 10 } };

// defining our own selector hook
const useSelector = (selectorFunction) => {
  
  const accessedProperty = selectorFunction(state);

  // accessedProperty will contain whatever is returned from the selectorFunction
  return accessedProperty;
}
```

Now, let's use our hook

```
// nested, subscribe to just the name property in user
const name = useSelector((state) => state.user.name);

// non-nested, subscribe to the complete user object
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
```

Talking about the performance, When an action is dispatched, `useSelector()` will do a reference comparison of the previous selector result value and the current result value. If they are different, the component will be forced to re-render. If they are the same, the component will not re-render.

So in your nested approach, `useSelector` will only do a reference equality comparison of the `name` value. AND in your non-nested approach, `useSelector` will do a reference equality comparison of the complete `user` object. In both cases, the result of the comparison determines whether the component should re-render. Chances are the non-nested approach will cause more re-renders than the nested approach because the non-nested approach is subscribing to more values than the nested approach.

Call `useSelector()` multiple times, with each call returning a single field value but it is also okay to use one `useSelector()` if further performance optimizations are not necessary